# How do you get the new Kairos Dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

The new Kairos Dragon is a legendary dragon in Dragonvale.

What do I need to do in order to breed one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some good information here:

[Dragonvale Kairos Dragon](http://www.dragonvalebreedingguide.com/dragon/kairos/tips-hints)

"You cannot breed or buy Kairos, you have to summon him! First you have to buy the Perch of Kairos (750,000 coins). Then you need to gather three artifacts: the Chronolith, the Time Claw and the Statue of Kairos. The artifacts are built by collecting 21 time fragments. They can be won on the Dragon Races or bought for 2,700 gems total."

Answer (score 3):

You can't buy, sell or breed the Kairos Dragon.
You need to buy the perch of Kairos, which comes under habitats or buildings. 
There are three parts to it and seven pieces to each part.
You must complete each of them before you can summon the dragon.
You can get pieces by racing on the dragon track. As far as I know, you can only get one per day.

Comment: Hi Bryan, welcome to Arqade.  FYI, I have tested, and can confirm that you can get more than one per day.  It is possible to land on the same one more than once though, which may result in you not getting a piece even though you landed on one.

Comment: Acually you can get more than a statue a day, in my case i just updated the game and i need one more piece for the first statue it only took 10 min

Answer (score 2):

The Karios Dragon in Dragonvale is not breedable, but you can earn it by winning Dragonvale Races apparently.

You could check out this guide about Dragonvale Breeding it might help you with others too

[Dragonvale Breeding Guide](http://macenstein.com/default/2012/05/macensteins-ultimate-dragonvale-breeding-guide/)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to get more then one per day, just slowly tap the race button so then it works! But you cannot get the kiaros by breeding.